# Where did the Marquis De Carabas get the Token?

Tags: neil-gaiman, neverwhere

The token is a small figurine, which is

> used to navigate the Beasts Maze, in Down Street. (Episode 5,  Down steet)

In "Episode 4, Black Friars", (iirc) we see the Marquis ask Old Bailey what the token is.
But I do not recall seeing the Marquis get it in the first place.

When and where did he get if from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Earlier in the story, Door and the Marquis visit Door's father's private study. The main focus of this scene is finding Portico's journal, which tells them to find Islington. Briefly mentioned though, is that the Marquis finds the token on Portico's desk and pockets it:

> Meanwhile, the Marquis examined the objects on Portico's desk. An inkwell; a chess-piece and bone die, a gold pocket-watch, several quill-feathers, and...
>
> *Interesting*
>
> It was a small statue of a boar, or a crouching bear, or perhaps a bull. It was hard to tell. [...] He picked it up casually, turned it over, curled his fingers around it.
>
> [...]
>
> The Marquis slipped the carving discreetly into an inside pocket.

Door doesn't notice. Interestingly, the Marquis does this even though he's apparently not sure what it is. Good instincts, I guess.

Comment: You're right. I remember that now.